# SharePoint access with Hightrust-add-in, SharePoint hosted custom WCF Service, Current User NULL

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, bearer-token, spcontext

I am working with an Azure hosted WebSerice which authenticates with an ADFS and creates an user access bearer token for communication with an on-premise SharePoint via a provider-hosted-add-in.

I can access SharePoint data via standard SharePoint REST API calls just fine. But when I try to call a custom WCF Service which is hosted in the same SharePoint I am not authenticated and as a result I do not have a current user, claim or identity in either the httpcontext, spcontext, operationcontext, thread.principal or ServiceSecurityContext.

Therefore I cannot access data in the SharePoint with the custom SharePoint hosted WCF Service.

How do I enforce authentication with the bearer access token in the same way the SharePoint REST API does?